# Build Gstreamer gst-plugins-bad 1.18.6 with support for Nvidia cuda, encoding/decoding, etc

Tags: c++, linux, gstreamer, nvidia, meson-build

Similar questions have been asked elsewhere on Stack Overflow. However, I do not believe any posts here give an answer relevant to the more recent releases of gst-plugins-bad.

I'd like to encode and decode H264 video streams with gstreamer using hardware support via my GTX1080 video card. I have been able to get this to work previously following [this guide](https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2021/04/gstreamer-nvenc-for-ubuntu-20-04/) on gst-plugins-bad 1.16.3, but my goal now is to access features available in 1.18.6. However, starting with 1.17.0, the build system for gst-plugins-bad changed from autoconf to Meson. I don't have ANY experience w/ Meson at all (honestly, I hadn't even heard of it until this point), and as such have no idea how to pass the proper arguments to build w/ nvidia support. Also, I wouldn't have come asking if there were any documentation available referencing what I'm trying to do here specific to later versions of gstreamer plugins. As far as I can tell, there isn't.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 with Cuda 11.8, Gstreamer 1.20.3, gst-plugins-bad 1.18.6.

For brevity is the output from nvidia-smi:

```
Wed Jan  4 14:42:19 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:42:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   54C    P2    40W / 240W |    652MiB /  8192MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1879      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                354MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2034      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               92MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12603      G   ...1/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      163MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20393      G   ...RendererForSitePerProcess       38MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that it's been renamed now and is installed with "bad" plugins by default when installing *gstreamer*. The name is *nvcodec*. See this https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/nvcodec/index.html?gi-language=c#nvcodec